# UI-Bootstrap, browser back button is not closing modal

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular-ui-bootstrap, jhipster

I created a project that contains some popup.I can close the popup via `$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')`.It is working on all my pages.But When I want to close the popup via browser back button,the popup is not closed.I noticed when I click the browser back button, run function is working.

```
function run(stateHandler, $uidModalStack, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart',function(event){
    //to do
  }
}
```

I cannot use `$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')` or something like that($uidModalStack).Do you have any idea?`

Comment: It is supposed to be $uibModalStack with a 'b' not a 'd', not sure it is an issue though it depends on your injection declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can force close all the modal when you change states using `$uibModalStack.dismissAll()`, but put it inside the `$stateChangeSuccess` handler

```
function run($rootScope, $uibModalStack) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a popup in my page and another popup is opened via button in this page..When i click the button new popup is not closed and previous popup is closed.Your idea is not working if i have 2 popup in one page.